# Regex to test if only ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried this but it returns true for both UTF-8 and ASCII:

```
 console.log(/[^w/]+/.test("abc123")) //true
 console.log(/[^w/]+/.test("ابت")) //true
```

Comment: Note that your regex as written currently tests that your string does not consist entirely of `w` and `/` characters. You probably meant to do `\w` instead of `w/`.

Comment: try using ^\w+$, you need to force it to match the complete string. \w should only match latin1. You can use \W for inverse match.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you meant `/[^\w]+/` but what you really want, from what I can gather, is:

```
console.log(/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/.test("abc123")) //true
console.log(/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/.test("abc_-8+")) //true
console.log(/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/.test("ابت")) //false
```

If you didn't actually mean to check the full ASCII set, you can just use:

```
console.log(/^[\w]+$/.test("abc123")) //true
console.log(/^[\w]+$/.test("abc_-8+")) //false
console.log(/^[\w]+$/.test("ابت")) //false
```

**About \x notation**

`\xFF` is a hexadecimal notation (list [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)) used in this example for the range `00` to `7F` to match the full ASCII character set. `\x00-\x7F` is functionally indentical to `a-z` in that it specifies a range, however we are using hex notation for reliable ranging

`\w` matches 'word' characters, which is the same as `[a-z0-9_]`

Comment: How about this `/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

Comment: @Sami — There are lots of ASCII characters that aren't letters or numbers.

Comment: @Sami As Quentin mentioned that's not the full ASCII set of characters, see my updated answer

Comment: @SmokeyPHP — That looks right to be, but it would be really great if you could link to documentation explaining how the \x syntax works and describing the ASCII character range in unicode.

Comment: Your first pattern for the full ASCII strangely does not work. It always returns `true`. However the second one(`/^[\w]+$/`) works.

Comment: @Sami `console.log(/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/.test("ابت"))` Doesn't return true - what are you getting true from that you didn't expect to?

Comment: @Quentin Am trying to find a decent link now, not much out there that explains it properly

Comment: Be aware that with `\w` Unicode-enabled regexp will (correctly) include Arabic 'word' characters as well (and Greek, Cyrillic, Thai ... and so on). The OP *probably* means "plain ASCII" but *may* also mean "Latin-1".

Comment: In case the OP indeed means to check *plain* ASCII: there is an expression for that: `/^[[:ascii:]]+$/`

Comment: @Jongware According to the table on [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) they're the same thing?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: `/^[[:ascii:]]+$/` and `/^\w+$/`, are not same!

Comment: @Cylian I know... I was referring to `[\x00-\x7F]`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: They are they same, but the shortcut is easier to remember. Kind like `[0-9]` versus `\d`.

Comment: failed for : sdfsdfsक ... A single character at the end failed it