# Restrict characters across all of a JSON schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I have some 3rd party software that isn't handling Unicode correctly. I want to represent this by providing a JSON Schema that disallows non-ascii characters. For an individual value, I can say

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
}
```

which describes what I'm looking for.

However, I'd like to be able to just say *all* strings in the schema match this pattern. I could do a custom format, but that doesn't seem much better:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "format": "ascii-string"
}
```

Is there a way to specify that I want every string to default to this format/pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by applying the schema specifying the pattern to all children recursively with a `$ref` pointing children of objects (with `additionalProperties`) and arrays (with `items`) back at itself. that would look like:

```
{
  "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "$ref": "#"
  },
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#"
  }
}
```

https://jsonschema.dev/s/YsM20

note that I used the pattern from your example, though that does not do the thing you said, restricting to ascii only. you can find a solution for that part elsewhere, e.g. [Regex to test if only ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017862/regex-to-test-if-only-ascii-characters/18017956)

you may also wish to add `"propertyNames": {"$ref": "#"}` since object property names are not normal values which the schema would apply to.

Comment: "If additionalProperties is an object, that object is a schema that will be used to validate any additional properties not listed in properties." Wow! I was more than half expecting the answer to be "you can't do this". Very cool!